# How to add PageBorders in docx.js?

Tags: javascript

Probably a noob question but I'm having a trouble adding a PageBorders to the document created using docx.js. I want a **border for each page** and not to the paragaraphs also how do I specify **color** and **size** properties.
Thanks for help!

So far I know what a section in docx.js is, how to add paragraphs to a section and headers and footers.

```js
doc.addSection({
    footers:{
        default: new Header({
            children: [new Paragraph({
                alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,
                children: [new TextRun({
                    children: [PageNumber.CURRENT]
                })]
            })]
        })
    },

    children: [headerPara, questionPara, codePara]
});

Packer.toBuffer(doc).then((buffer) => {
    fs.writeFileSync("test.docx", buffer);
});
```

Comment: Hi @aditya-wankhede welcome to Stack Overflow! Please can you provide a code example of what you've got so far

Answer (score 0):

To add borders for your page, follow this example:

```
doc.addSection({
  children: [],
  properties: {
    pageBorderLeft: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderRight: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderTop: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderBottom: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    }
  }
});
```

For your code:

```
doc.addSection({
footers:{
    default: new Header({
        children: [new Paragraph({
            alignment: AlignmentType.CENTER,
            children: [new TextRun({
                children: [PageNumber.CURRENT]
            })]
        })]
    })
},

children: [headerPara, questionPara, codePara],
properties: {
    pageBorderLeft: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderRight: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderTop: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    },
    pageBorderBottom: {
      style: docx.BorderStyle.SINGLE,
      size: 3,
      color: 'auto',
      space: 1
    }
  }
});

Packer.toBuffer(doc).then((buffer) => {
    fs.writeFileSync("test.docx", buffer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this block from Angular-docx integration. Adding `style: BorderStyle.SINGLE` plays major role in border creation.

```
properties: {    
   pageBorderLeft: {
              style: BorderStyle.SINGLE,
              size: 3,
              color: 'auto',
              space: 2
            },
   pageBorderRight: {
              style: BorderStyle.SINGLE,
              size: 3,
              color: 'auto',
              space: 2
            },
    pageBorderTop: {
              style: BorderStyle.SINGLE,
              size: 3,
              color: 'auto',
              space: 2
            },
    pageBorderBottom: {
              style: BorderStyle.SINGLE,
              size: 3,
              color: 'auto',
              space: 2
            }
}
```